# responsive @media query to remove style declarations

Tags: css, html, media-queries

I'm unfamiliar with @media queries, and what I'm trying to accomplish is a responsive removal/alteration of certain CSS when the browser viewing is shrunk below a certain resolution, or a mobile device viewing the page is also below that same specified resolution.

I need `.side` to remove `float: left; position: fixed; width: 150px;` when below 500px width resolution, and `.main` to remove `border-left: 1px solid #000; margin: 0 0 0 170px;`

```
.side {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  width: 150px;
}

.main {
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0 0 0 170px;
}
```

Any help or explanation is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to look up how to do this at all?

Comment: study here 1st, http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In this way you can do this

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {

    .side {
      float: none;
      position: static;
      width: auto;
    }

    .main {
      border-left:0;
      margin: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a pretty simple way to do it, just use all: unset, like this

```
@media ("your condition") {
   .yourClass {
      all:unset
   }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation or a source with a small summary.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

```
.side {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  width: 150px;
}

.main {
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0 0 0 170px;
  width: auto;
}
@media only screen and (max-device-width : 500px) {
  .side {
    float: none;
    position: static;
    width: auto;
  }
  .main {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```